# Using Toggle to Display information in table once selection is made

Tags: javascript, select, toggle, hide, show-hide

I have really been struggling with this for a while now and I am down to the wire and really need help. I want to display an 1 row / 4 column table on the page with a single drop down menu in the far left column, then based on what is selected in from that drop down I want specific information to display in the remaining 1 row / 3 columns. Here is what I have to far I just cant get my data to display in the columns I want them to.

```
 <html>
<body onLoad="hideAll()">
<script>
function toggleOption(thisselect) {
    var selected = thisselect.options[thisselect.selectedIndex].value;
    toggleRow(selected);
}

function toggleRow(id) {
  var row = document.getElementById(id);
  if (row.style.display == '') {
    row.style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
     row.style.display = '';
  }
}

function showRow(id) {
  var row = document.getElementById(id);
  row.style.display = '';
}

function hideRow(id) {
  var row = document.getElementById(id);
  row.style.display = 'none';
}

function hideAll() {
 hideRow('optionA');
 hideRow('optionB');
 hideRow('optionC');
 hideRow('optionD');
}

</script>

<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Part Number</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Material</th>
    </tr>    
<tr>
    <td>
<select id="options" onchange="toggleOption(this)">
<option value="optionA">3/16"</option>
<option value="optionB">1/4"</option>
<option value="optionC">5/16"</option>
<option value="optionD">3/8"</option>
</select>
</td>
<tr id="optionA"><td>3BMH</td><td>Brass Hose Mender</td><td>Brass</td></tr>
<tr id="optionB"><td>4BMH</td><td>Brass Hose Mender</td><td>Brass</td></tr>
<tr id="optionC"><td>5BMH</td><td>Brass Hose Mender</td><td>Brass</td></tr>
<tr id="optionD"><td>6BMH</td><td>Brass Hose Mender</td><td>Brass</td></tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may add  hideAll(); before toggleRow(selected); in the function toggleOption.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are encountering is that your rows (tr) should be cells (td), but this is a very bad approach, what you should do is to use only a row whit four cells inside, the first one with your select and the others empty, and then inject your data to those (just change the innerHTML of your td), here is a example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        function toggleoption(opt) {
            var selected = opt.options[opt.selectedIndex].value;
            if ("optiona" === selected) {
                document.getElementById("partn").innerHTML = "3BMH";
                document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = "Brass Hose Mender";
                document.getElementById("mat").innerHTML = "Brass";
            } else if ("optionb" === selected) {
                document.getElementById("partn").innerHTML = "4BMH";
                document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = "Brass Hose Mender";
                document.getElementById("mat").innerHTML = "Brass";
            } else if ("optionc" === selected) {
                document.getElementById("partn").innerHTML = "5BMH";
                document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = "Brass Hose Mender";
                document.getElementById("mat").innerHTML = "Brass";
            } else if ("optiond" === selected) {
                document.getElementById("partn").innerHTML = "6BMH";
                document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = "Brass Hose Mender";
                document.getElementById("mat").innerHTML = "Brass";
            } 
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Size</th>
          <th>Part Number</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Material</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <select id="options" onchange="toggleoption(this)">
              <option value="optiona">3/16"</option>
              <option value="optionb">1/4"</option>
              <option value="optionc">5/16"</option>
              <option value="optiond">3/8"</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td id="partn"></td>
            <td id="desc"></td>
            <td id="mat"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course this code can be largely improved and i'll strongly recommend the use of jquery, but that is up to you.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time and helping me with this. I was trying to stay away from jquery simply because I am afraid to lose speed on the page. With moving to JQuery would you suggest sticking with the .toggle?

Comment: I really don't, to do it this way you need 3 cells per option and a way to wrapping them together (i think is what you where trying to do whit the rows), you could do it by setting the same class and different ids started by the same string according to each cell and then toggle them, but it's going to be a messy and hard to maintain code.